# Как можно сохранить ссылку на созданный обьект, чтобы изменить его после добавления в коллекцию?

Tags: c#

Надо сломать HashSet, для чего тредуется добавить в него объект, после этого изменить его (извне коллекции). Есть следующий класс:

```
public class GhostsTask : 
    IFactory<Vector>, IMagic
{
    public void DoMagic() {}

    Vector IFactory<Vector>.Create() {}
}
```

Как в методе `Create` можно сохранить ссылку на последний созданный объект, чтобы изменить его методом `DoMagic()` уже после добавления в `HashSet` :

```
TGhostsTask task = new TGhostsTask();
var ghostItem = task.Create();

var set = new HashSet<TItem> { ghostItem };
Assert.IsTrue(set.Contains(task.Create()));

task.DoMagic();
Assert.AreEqual(1, set.Count, "HashSet содержит элементы после DoMagic()");
Assert.AreEqual(ghostItem, set.ToArray()[0], "единственный элемент HashSet после DoMagic() все еще ghostItem ");
Assert.IsFalse(set.Contains(ghostItem), "ghostItem не находится через HashSet.Contains() после DoMagic()");

set.Add(ghostItem);
Assert.AreEqual(2, set.Count, "HashSet Add и Count перестают работать корректно после DoMagic()");
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, завести какое-нибудь поле в классе `LastObject` и после создания очередного объекта его перезаписывать.

Далее, спокойно можешь его использовать в любом методе класса.

Только не забудь проверить на `null`-это будет значить, что объектов создано не было.

Comment: Естественно я так и сделал сразу. Не работает. Почему - сам не понимаю

  public void DoMagic()
  {
   lastVector?.Add(new Vector(1, 1));
  }

  Vector IFactory<Vector>.Create()
  {
   lastVector = new Vector(0, 0);
   return lastVector;
  }
  private Vector lastVector;

Comment: А дебаггер что говорит? По идее, код простой и косяк сразу можно увидеть пройдясь по шагам по коду.

Comment: Я мог запутаться, из-за того что сейчас пробую работать в Rider. Дебагер не может показать ссылки, но судя по всему сохранённый объект и тот, что я вернул фабричным методом, лежат по разным ссылкам.

Comment: статическое поле с экземплярным не путаешь?

Comment: Сейчас понял ошибку. Я пересоздал объект в `Create`, отсюда и ошибка. Надо было сразу инициализировать его в поле, а `Create` просто возвращать поле.